# Example of the non-commutative ring with the set of units are commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I was looking for an Example of the non-commutative ring with the set of units are commutative. it will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take the ring of [noncommutative polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) $R\langle X_1, X_2\rangle$ over any commutative ring $R$. The units will be the same as in R.

NB: this is a special case of Mike Debellevue's answer, with $M$ being the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on two generators.

Answer (score 3):

For any monoid $M$ with no units and trivial center, and any commutative ring $R$, the monoid ring $R[M]$ will have the same units as $R$.

Comment: Nice! My example is a special case when $M$ is the free monoid on two generators.